# Orchard CMS adding fields to page in custom recipe?

Tags: orchardcms

Is there any way to have a custom recipe add some text and image fields to the page? It looks like part of the recipe handles commands, but I can't find any commands that do this at @ http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Using-the-command-line-interface

**Update**

Thanks for the response Bertrand, but there are some issues with that.

I exported everything for a recipe from a tenant that has 1. added fields, 2. added parts to the Page along with 3. an added List and 4. an added container widget to the Default layer that shows the list.

```
  <Metadata>
    <Types>
      <Page ContentTypeSettings.Draftable="True" TypeIndexing.Included="true">
        <TagsPart />
        <LocalizationPart />
        <TitlePart/>
        <AutoroutePart />
        <ContainablePart />
        <AmazonProductsPart />
        <YouTubeVideosPart />
      </Page>
    </Types>
    <Parts>
      <BodyPart BodyPartSettings.FlavorDefault="html" />
      <Page ContentPartSettings.Attachable="True">
        <Thumbnail.ImageField DisplayName="Thumbnail" ImageFieldSettings.MaxHeight="75" ImageFieldSettings.MaxWidth="75" ImageFieldSettings.Required="False" ImageFieldSettings.AlternateText="True" ImageFieldSettings.ResizeAction="Validate" />
        <PageImage.ImageField DisplayName="PageImage" ImageFieldSettings.MaxHeight="250" ImageFieldSettings.MaxWidth="0" ImageFieldSettings.Required="False" ImageFieldSettings.AlternateText="True" ImageFieldSettings.ResizeAction="Resize" />
        <PreContent.TextField DisplayName="PreContent" ImageFieldSettings.MaxHeight="0" ImageFieldSettings.MaxWidth="0" ImageFieldSettings.Required="False" ImageFieldSettings.AlternateText="False" ImageFieldSettings.ResizeAction="Validate" TextFieldSettings.Flavor="Html" TextFieldSettings.Required="False" />
        <PostContent.TextField DisplayName="PostContent" ImageFieldSettings.MaxHeight="0" ImageFieldSettings.MaxWidth="0" ImageFieldSettings.Required="False" ImageFieldSettings.AlternateText="False" ImageFieldSettings.ResizeAction="Validate" TextFieldSettings.Flavor="Html" TextFieldSettings.Required="False" />
      </Page>
    </Parts>
  </Metadata>
```

...

```
  <Data>
    <List Id="/alias=page-list" Status="Published">
      <CommonPart Owner="/User.UserName=admin" CreatedUtc="2012-05-26T22:52:20Z" PublishedUtc="2012-05-26T22:57:37Z" ModifiedUtc="2012-05-26T22:57:37Z" />
      <AutoroutePart Alias="page-list" UseCustomPattern="false" />
      <AdminMenuPart AdminMenuPosition="2" OnAdminMenu="false" />
      <MenuPart MenuText="Page List" MenuPosition="3" OnMainMenu="false" />
      <ContainerPart ItemContentType="Page" ItemsShown="true" Paginated="true" PageSize="10" OrderByProperty="CommonPart.CreatedUtc" OrderByDirection="1" />
      <TitlePart Title="Page List" />
    </List>
    <ContainerWidget Id="" Status="Published">
      <CommonPart Owner="/User.UserName=admin" Container="/Layer.LayerName=Default" CreatedUtc="2012-05-26T22:55:42Z" PublishedUtc="2012-05-26T22:55:42Z" ModifiedUtc="2012-05-26T22:55:42Z" />
      <WidgetPart Title="Page List" Position="1" Zone="AsideFirst" RenderTitle="false" />
      <ContainerWidgetPart Container="/alias=page-list" PageSize="5" OrderByProperty="CommonPart.CreatedUtc" OrderByDirection="1" ApplyFilter="false" FilterByProperty="CustomPropertiesPart.CustomOne" FilterByOperator="=" />
    </ContainerWidget>
  </Data>
```

I then inject that into a copy of the default recipe with the appropriate modules activated.

When creating a new tenant from that recipe,

1. All the modules are enabled, good
2. The list is created, good
3. The page has the added parts, good
4. The page does not have the added fields, bad
5. The container widget does not exist, bad

It looks like the part fields are not added, and the widget was not created.

I did another simple test, and it looks like a bug?

Repro Steps:

1. Add fields to the page
2. Add a widget
3. Export everything
4. delete the widget
5. Import the exported xml
   Expected: The widget to be back
   Actual: the widget is still missing

is the recipe suppose to honor page fields and widgets, did I do something wrong, or is this a bug?

**Update**

Okay, this has to be a bug. When manually adding the fields, I get this message even though it isn't showing the fields: "A field with the same name already exists."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a command, this is supported by recipes without that. The easiest way to get an example is to add a field from the admin UI, and then export the metadata and examine the recipe that created.

Comment: you are truly the in-house orchard export. Again, you are right and I wasn't aware of the import/export module. After tinkering with it, behold all the magical meta is there. Thank you!

Comment: the stuff from the export that refers to page fields doesn't get honored during an import or creating a new tenant from the recipe. Is this a bug? See question update.

Comment: Please file a bug with the repro steps. Thanks.